# Are any of these ships from other movies?

Tags: object-identification, spaceballs

At the end of Spaceballs there is a scene set at a diner / gas station / space station thing.

Here we clearly see several Winnebago style ships as well as the Millennium Falcon.

[image]

**Are any of these other vehicles from other properties?**

One of them sort of looks like a NASA space shuttle (with the top ripped off). Another has the look of a flying saucer, and then one looks like a Concorde jet.

Comment: Dont forget the SAM or Intercontinental Missile next to the Saucer

Comment: The one at the far left looks familiar, but I can't place it.

Comment: I don't know about the ships, but *The Mighty Ducks I, II, III*, *Jingle All the Way* and *A Prairie Home Companion* movies contain scenes that were shot on location at Mickey's Dining Car, which looks quite a bit like Gus's. http://www.mickeysdiningcar.com/, but then again, most train car diners look like Gus's.

Comment: It's not the Shuttle with the topped ripped off; it's just the payload bay open

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the lionshare are trucks, buses, and RV's with space ship flare stuck on.  Other than that from you have a Millennium Falcon, what looks be a US Space Shuttle gutted for parts, your bog standard 50's UFO, and a SAM (possibly a US rim-8 talos, but I am not a sam expert) on a trailer.  I don't recognize the top right one, it seems to be a kitbash of a few different ships.  And the bottom right one seems to be a delivery truck with pointy bits on the nose, plus the rocket on the back.

Answer (score 4):

[image: obligatory hand-drawn circle]

The green one is the Millennium Falcon, as you note.

The red one is the US Space Shuttle with the payload bay open, like this:
[image: STS-121]
<sub>By NASA - http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-121/html/iss013e48788.html, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2177068</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Top right one reminds me of the Eastern Alliance cruiser from 1978 Battlestar Galactica episodes (Season 1, Episode 19, "Experiment in Terra") - maybe even flipped upside down or had its nose chopped off.

[image]

[image]

http://www.universalhartland.com/code/galc13ea.shtml

Note, however, that modelmakers routinely kit bash (even digitally in these days of the computer) *(Kit bashing is a practice whereby a new scale model is created by taking pieces out of other model kits)* to get their models for filming, some more so than others: and some just keeping in line with what's been established in the film already (RV's with wings, etc); and some could just be keeping up with the humor, and in-jokes (probably what the classic flying saucer is - I did hope it was the saucer from the classic "The Invaders" (a Quinn Martin production!) but the windows are wrong), so could be nods but also could be anything. *(That shuttle looks like its cockpit has been bashed up)*

Answer (score -1):

The one to the left of the runway is similar to the Fairchild Republic C-119 Flying Boxcar/AC-119 Shadow/Stinger aircraft, as shown in the following image from an aerial photo taken during the Vietnam War.

[image]